# Grind 1/8" - 1/16" off 12" zinc plated bar

Tags: repair, metal, grinder

I'm fixing a broken rib on a patio umbrella. I have a 1/2" square zinc-plated steel rod I'd like to insert in the broken rib. The rib itself is a 1/2" hollow square, so I need to grind the rod down a bit to fit inside.

Is this something I could do with a dremel? If so what type of head?

Comment: Would probably want a grinding disk/wheel, instead of a round or cone shape.  Depending on length you might want an angle grinder or bench grinder.  A bench grinder will probably give better consistent finish size.  With zinc a face mask might be useful, eye protection is a must have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in less than a month. Use a bench grinder, angle grinder , belt grinder , etc. ,anything except a Dremel. Because it is only 12" long , it could probably be done manually with coarse rasp or bastard files.